# Javascript function For Alpha Numeric in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#

My problem is when I am using the below function for validating my address text box, I can put special character into the text box, but I don't need special character into my validating text box.

So how will avoid special character entering to textbox without effecting numeric entering. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="" type="text/javascript">
function alphanumeric_Address(e) {

    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (event) keycode = event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;

    if ((keycode >= 47 && keycode <= 57) ||
        (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) ||
        (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```